# Clang static analyzer on iPhone app showing errors with latest version

Tags: iphone, objective-c, clang-static-analyzer

When I run my code through the version 252 checker binary, there are no analysis errors.  However, when I change to use the latest 253 checker, it returns a slew of errors, all of which do not make any sense.  For example, here is an image of an error that it shows in my Safari browser after the scan-build script is complete:

[image: Clang static analyzer error]

This is a pretty common error that shows up in the error listing. As you can see, the method name has Copy at the end of it, but it is still reporting as incorrectly named.

Here is the breakdown of errors that I am now getting with checker version 253:

```
Bug Summary

Results in this analysis run are based on analyzer build checker-253.

Bug Type    Quantity
All Bugs    83  

Dead code   
Unreachable code    17  

Memory (Core Foundation/Objective-C)    
Bad release 19  
Leak of returned object 23  
Object sent -autorelease too many times 24
```

The autorelease errors seem to be related to the fact that the analyzer is unable to see that the Copy methods are actually correctly named, and I tried to look for an example of unreachable code, but I could not really find any patterns or explanations of those errors, as the errors were all lines of code inside simple if statements.  Here is one for example:

[image: Yet another Clang analyzer error]

I suppose that this could be some bugs that were introduced in the latest version of checker that is causing these to show up as errors.  Is there something else (some kind of build setting or issue with the scan-build script) that I could be missing here?

Comment: I don't think *GetAllNewOrModifiedCopy* matches the naming conventions...

Comment: I tried a bunch of different method names to see if it would make the error go away (including addedOrModifiedcopy, which does not have get or new in the name), and it still gives the same error in the same place.

Comment: Try `CopyAllNewOrModified`. It's possible the checker has been restricted to only considering "copy" and "mutableCopy" at the beginning of a method name.

Comment: Kevin, see my comment in the accepted answer below, I went with your suggestion for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, method names should start with lower case letters, not uppercase (save for abbreviations like URL).   It may be that the static analyzer is tripping over the uppercase "Get".

Next, even with a lowercase "get", the method does not follow convention.

To quote the documentation:

> Use “get” only for methods that return
>   objects and values indirectly. You
>   should use this form for methods only
>   when multiple items need to be
>   returned.

Thus, the analyzer is correctly identifying an issue.

I would suggest following the guidelines and using something like:

```
+ (NSArray *) modifiedOrNewPeople: (FMDatabase *) aDatabase;
```

Which would release an autoreleased array.  If there is some reason you can't return an autoreleased object, please comment.

Comment: Isn't using "new" in the method name dangerous?

Comment: Yup. Fixed.  Thanks.  The analyzer would have complained about that, too.

Comment: I took one of my classes and changed the method name to a naming similar to your suggestion, and switched all the callers to expect an autoreleased object instead of retained, and the analyzer stopped complaining.  The problem is that I have a lot of classes using this kind of method being called in lots of places, so I worry about changing code that is working fine.  Also, I don't like to leave a lot of autorelease objects lying around.

Comment: Well, here is where I am leaving it for now.  I wanted to keep my class methods returning retained objects, and the only method name that seems to satisfy the 253 checker is copyAddedOrModified.  I tried addedOrModifiedCopy and addedOrModifiedcopy, and both of these give an error in the analyzer.  So it would seem that they most likely tried to beef up the checking against naming conventions in this latest checker build, but the copy keyword is not being seen if it is not at the beginning, even though the guidelines say that is should not matter.

Comment: Got a link to the guidelines stating that?   There is either a bug in the docs or the analyzer.

Comment: Well, here is a link to an article from Apple on Objective-C memory management naming: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html Also, this rule is shown right in the analyzer error output, see #4 in the first image above.

Comment: Cool.  Thank you.  That doc is wrong.  Bug filed (<rdar://problem/8839068>).  Should just be prefixes like 'copy' and 'mutableCopy'.  I.e. `arrayOfCopiedPeople` implies an autoreleased array that has ownership of the copied people objects.